# Diagonalizability of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $ T: V -> V $ be a linear transformation and let $ \lambda_1 , ... , \lambda_k $ be distinct eigenvalues of T. 
Suppose the characteristic polynomial of T is $ (x-\lambda_1)^{n_1} ...(x-\lambda_k)^{n_k}$.
Then $T$ is diagonalizable iff $rank(T-\lambda_iId) = rank(T-\lambda_iId)^2 $  $\forall $ $i$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Jordan normal form of matrices?

Comment: I'm familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you indicated that you're familiar with the Jordan normal form of matrices, you know that $(T-\lambda_iI)^{n_i}$ [has nullity $n_i$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#The_Nullity_of_.28A_.E2.88.92_.CE.BB_I.29k). Therefore, to say $\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda_iI)=\operatorname{rank}(T-\lambda_iI)^2$ is to say $$\operatorname{null}(T-\lambda_iI)=\operatorname{null}(T-\lambda_iI)^2 = \ldots = \operatorname{null}(T-\lambda_iI)^{n_i},$$
of dimension $n_i$, which is to say that $T$ has $n_i$ linearlly independent eigenvectors belonging to $\lambda_i$, which in turns is equivalent to diagonlizability.